# Solving $p^2=2xq^2+2yq+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

What are the conditions of solvability of the equation $p^2=2xq^2+2yq+1$ where

$p,q$ being prime and $x,y\in \mathbb{N}$?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1776734/how-to-find-integer-solutions-to-m2-5n22n1/1776757#1776757

Comment: That's hardly relevant, unless we do it the other way around (solving for p, q). I thought we were solving for x, y. Or... are we, really? A clarification is needed.

Comment: Solving for x,y is preferred.

Comment: Then the equation is of the form $ax+by=c$, $c=p^2-1$, which has been solved, among many other MSE-questions, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/how-to-find-solutions-of-linear-diophantine-ax-by-c).

Answer (score 0):

The right side of the equation is an odd number, therefore $p$ too.

$q$ devides $p+1$ or $p-1$. Therefore $p:=2kq\pm 1$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

$(2kq\pm 1)^2=4k^2 q^2\pm 4kq +1=2xq^2+2yq+1$

You can set $x=2k^2$ and $y=\pm 2k$ independend of $q$.

Because of $y>0$ (means $y=2k$) you can only choose $p:=2kq+1$.